# How can I return unMutualContacts with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return the unMutualContacts of a user (the contacts that they aren't mutual friends with). I guess the question could be: How to return **nodes** that **user Y** is **:CONNECTED** with but NOT return **nodes** that **user X** is **:CONNECTED** to. This is the query:

```
MATCH (o:User { id: y })-[con:CONNECTED]-(users:User)
MATCH (u:User { id: x })-[ucon:CONNECTED]-(viewerUsers:User)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:CONNECTED]-(users)
RETURN users
```

I want to return the users who're connected to **y** that aren't connected to **x**. I also tried: `WHERE NOT (o)-[:PL_CONNECTED]-(viewerUsers)` instead of `NOT (u)-[:CONNECTED]-(users)` without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's going to be easier to work with lists. I noticed you're using plural variable names `users` and `viewerUsers`, but these don't represent lists, they represent the individual match per line. I find it helps if you only reserve plural variable names for lists, that can avoid some confusion.

While we could use MATCH and the collect() to get the list of users to exclude, we'll take a shortcut and use pattern comprehension to get the list from the match in a single line. And once we have that list of users to exclude, we can use that in a WHERE clause for connected users of `y` to ensure we filter out any that should be excluded (since they're connected to `x`).

```
WITH [(:User { id: x })-[:CONNECTED]-(user:User) | user] as excluded
MATCH (:User { id: y })-[:CONNECTED]-(user:User)
WHERE NOT user IN excluded
RETURN user
```

Alternately you could take both lists and do list subtraction via APOC procedures:

```
WITH [(:User { id: x })-[:CONNECTED]-(user:User) | user] as excluded,
 [(:User { id: y })-[:CONNECTED]-(user:User) | user] as users
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(users, excluded) as users
```

Note that this one will only return a single list, so if you wanted to get back to multiple records with a single user each you would need to UNWIND users back to user.